# My system's log time seems strange

Tags: linux

I have a cron session running every minute so I can get a log in `/var/log/message` every minute.

But sometimes the timestamps of the log messages go abnormal.

For example, a `12:20:20` message comes before a `12:10:00` message, and after this message is a `12:11:00` message.

This will last for a while and then become normal.

Comment: Does the log receive receive log messages from the network? If yes, your nodes might be out of sync.

Comment: Not form network, it is a local log

Answer (score 0):

does the process take longer than a minute to run?  If so, you could be seeing the message written at the end of processing using the start time of the process which could make some messages appear out of sync.

Comment: Yes, the process may take longer than a minute, but not all the times
And I thought that it is just a log, maybe a syslog(...) call, and the time was generated by the syslog-ng , is it?
And I write a short test just like this:
Time()->localtime()->write()
And I run it for a day, and Find this scene again
My system runs a network server and some fs test program(a distributed network fs test suit)
May the heavily io workload or network load lead to this？And why？